# EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime error when setting a static property in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Working on an IoT program, but still getting my foot in the door, what the program is supposed to do now is just show a message when the user successfully authenticates using the Touch ID. And it should do that every time the user opens the program whether it is launching for the first time or it is becoming active after being in background.
Program runs, but when it reaches the block where it tried to set a static boolean property that tracks the authentication state it gives me this error:[image: error]

Here is the full code:

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        print("Launching...")
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        print("Exiting...")
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        ViewController.userIsAuthenticated = false
        print("Exited")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        print("Opening...")
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        print("Opened")
        let viewInstance = ViewController()
        viewInstance.authenticateUser()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        print("Terminating!")
    }


}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

@IBDesignable class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //MARK: Properties
    static var userIsAuthenticated: Bool{
        get{
            return false
        }
        set{
            userIsAuthenticated = newValue
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Authentication Successful!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let viewInstance = ViewController()
            viewInstance.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.3, green: 0.48, blue: 0.78, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func authenticateUser(){
        if ViewController.userIsAuthenticated != true {
            let authenticateUser = LAContext()
            var authenticationError: NSError? = nil
            let authenticationReason = "Authentication is needed to access your house!"
            if authenticateUser.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authenticationError){
                authenticateUser.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: authenticationReason, reply: {(success, error) in
                    if(success){
                        ViewController.userIsAuthenticated = true
                    }else{
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            }else{
                print("Authentication Error!", authenticationError!)
            }
        }
    }

    func displayAnAlert(title:String?, message: String?) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            print("Cancel")
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
            print("OK")
        })

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }

}
```

---

### EDIT

---

NOW the error is gone but the alert doesn't show up and it gives me this error:[image: error.2]

Here is the new code:

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        print("Launching...")
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        print("Exiting...")
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        ViewController.userIsAuthenticated = false
        print("Exited")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        print("Opening...")
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        print("Opened")
        let viewInstance = ViewController()
        viewInstance.authenticateUser()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        print("Terminating!")
    }


}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

@IBDesignable class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //MARK: Properties
    static var userIsAuthenticated: Bool!{
        didSet{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Authentication Successful!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let viewInstance = ViewController()
            viewInstance.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.3, green: 0.48, blue: 0.78, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func authenticateUser(){
        if ViewController.userIsAuthenticated != true {
            let authenticateUser = LAContext()
            var authenticationError: NSError? = nil
            let authenticationReason = "Authentication is needed to access your house!"
            if authenticateUser.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authenticationError){
                authenticateUser.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: authenticationReason, reply: {(success, error) in
                    if(success){
                        ViewController.userIsAuthenticated = true
                    }else{
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            }else{
                print("Authentication Error!", authenticationError!)
            }
        }
    }

    func displayAnAlert(title:String?, message: String?) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            print("Cancel")
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
            print("OK")
        })

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: `userIsAuthenticated = newValue` causes an infinite loop. It calls the setter which calls the setter which calls ....  –  Remove the line.

Comment: @vadian  but if i removed that line, how will the userIsAuthenticated get set?

Comment: userIsAuthenticated is a computed property (not a stored property)

Comment: `userIsAuthenticated` is set implicitly. You might mix it up with the `didSet` observer.

Comment: I tried doing so, but it tells me it needs to be initialized and whenever i try to set a value for it in the init() function it doesn't get set and still gives the same error

Comment: @vadian  i tried removing that line but looks like it doesn't get set automatically because it keeps getting the authentication forever

Comment: Okay i managed to fix it and now it is working but the alert doesn't show up, I'll edit the post with the new code and error

Comment: Your `get` for `userIsAuthenticated` always returns `false`, which might explain why "it keeps getting the authentication forever". It appears you may have some misconception over how properties work in Swift, maybe it is time for a review of [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) in the *The Swift Programming Language*? HTH

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment on your question you have edited the question with a new error stating that you are attempting to present your alert on a view which is not in the window heirarchy. This is because you have just created a brand new view:

```
let viewInstance = ViewController()
```

which is not associated with any window... hence the error.

Presumably you did't want a new view at all, but probably the view you already have that is performing `authenticateUser()`. If `userIsAuthenticated` was an instance property that view would simply be available as `self`, but your property is `static` and so this is not the case.

There is no simple answer to your problem without redesigning your solution for you, and that is something you need to do! Time to take a step back and think. Ask yourself why your property is `static`, why you are trying to issue alerts from a property setter, etc.

HTH